# How do I make A and B run in parallel?

Tags: javascript

How do I make A and B run in parallel?

```
async function runAsync(funcName)
{ 
   console.log(' Start=' + funcName.name); 
   funcName(); 
   console.log(' End===' + funcName.name) 
}; 



function A()
{
    var nowDateTime = Date.now();
    var i = 0;
    
    while( Date.now() < nowDateTime + 1000)
      i++;
   
   console.log(' A i= ' + i) ;
}

function B()
{
    var nowDateTime = Date.now();
    var i = 0;
    
    while( Date.now() < nowDateTime + 1000)
      i++;
      
   console.log(' B i= ' + i) ;
}

runAsync(A);
runAsync(B);
```

The console shows that A starts first and B starts after A:

```
 Start=A
 A i= 6515045
 End===A
 Start=B
 B i= 6678877
 End===B
```

Note:

I am trying to use **async** for Chrome/Firefox, and keep the JS code compatible with IE11.

This C# code generates the proxy function `runAsync`:

```
    if (isEI())
        Current.Response.Write(" function runAsync(funcName){ setImmediate(funcName); }; ");
    else
        Current.Response.Write(" async function runAsync(funcName){ funcName(); } ");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/n2huzfxj/28/

**Update.**

My goal was to parse information and prepare (indexing and adding triggers) for an immediate response after user input. While the user is viewing the information, the background function has 3-10 seconds to execute, and the background function should not block UI and mouse and keyboard responses. Here is the solution for all browsers, including IE11.

Created a new **Plugin** to simulate parallel execution of funcRun during idle times.

**Example of an original code:**

```
 $("input[name$='xxx'],...").each( function(){runForThis(this)}, ticksToRun );
```

**The updated code using the Plugin:**

```
  $(document).zParallel({
        name: "Example",
        selectorToRun: "input[name$='xxx'],...",
        funcRun: runForThis
    });
```

**Plugin.**

```
(function ($)
{
// Plugin zParallel

    function zParallel(options)
    {
        var self = this;

        self.defaults = {
            selectorToRun: null,
            funcRun: null,
            afterEnd: null,
            lengthToRun: 0,
            iterScheduled: 0,
            ticksToRun: 50,
            showDebugInfo: true
        };

        self.opts = $.extend({}, self.defaults, options);
    }

    zParallel.prototype = {

        init: function ()
        {
            var self = this;

            var selector = $(self.opts.selectorToRun);
            self.lengthToRun = selector.length;

            if (self.lengthToRun > 0)
            {
                self.arrayOfThis = new Array;
                selector.each(function ()
                {
                    self.arrayOfThis.push(this);
                });
                self.arrayOfThis.reverse();
                self.opts.iterScheduled = 0;
                self.whenStarted = Date.now();
                self.run();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.out('zParallel: selector is empty');
                return false;
            }
        },

        run: function () 
        {
            var self = this;
            var nextTicks = Date.now() + self.opts.ticksToRun;
            var _debug = self.opts.showDebugInfo;

            if (self.opts.iterScheduled === 0)
            {
                nextTicks -= (self.opts.ticksToRun + 1);   // Goto to Scheduling run
            }

            var count = 0;
            var comOut = "";
            while ((self.lengthToRun = self.arrayOfThis.length) > 0)
            {
                var curTicks = Date.now();

                if (_debug)
                {
                    comOut = self.opts.name + " |" + (curTicks - self.whenStarted)/1000 + "s| ";
                    if (self.opts.iterScheduled === 0)
                        this.out("START " + comOut + " remaining #" + self.lengthToRun);
                }

                if (curTicks > nextTicks)
                {
                    self.opts.iterScheduled++;

                    if ('requestIdleCallback' in window)
                    {
                        if (_debug)
                            this.out(comOut + "requestIdleCallback , remaining #" + self.lengthToRun + " executed: #" + count);
                        window.requestIdleCallback(function () { self.run() }, { timeout: 1000 });
                    } else
                    {
                        if (_debug)
                            this.out(comOut + "setTimeout, remaining #" + self.lengthToRun + " executed: #" + count);
                        setTimeout(function (self) { self.run()}, 10, self);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                var nexThis = self.arrayOfThis.pop();
                self.opts.funcRun(nexThis);
                count++;
            }

            if (self.opts.afterEnd!== null)
               self.opts.afterEnd();

            if (_debug)
                this.out("END " + comOut + " executed:  #" + count);

            return true;
        },
        out: function (str)
        {
            if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
                console.log(str);
        }
    };


    $.fn.zParallel = function (options)
    {
        var rev = new zParallel(options);
        rev.init();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

// **Examples.**

```
(function ($)
{

    var tab1 = $('#tbl1');
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        $("<tr>"+
        "<td>#" + i + "</td>"+
        "<td><input id='a_" + i + "' value='" + i + "' >"+
        "</td><td><input id='b_" + i + "' value='" + i + "' ></td></tr>")
            .appendTo(tab1);

    $(document).zParallel({
        name: "A",
        selectorToRun: "input[id^='a_']",
        funcRun: function (nextThis)
        {
            var $this = $(nextThis);

            var nowDateTime = Date.now();
            var i = 0;
            while( Date.now() < nowDateTime + 2)
                  i++;

            $this.val( i );
            if (i > 100)
                $this.css('color', 'green').css('font-weight', 'bold');
            else
                $this.css('color', 'blue');
        }
    });


    $(document).zParallel({
        name: "B",
        selectorToRun: "input[id^='b_']",
        funcRun: function (nextThis)
        {
            var $this = $(nextThis);

            var nowDateTime = Date.now();
            var i = 0;
            while( Date.now() < nowDateTime + 2)
                  i++;

            $this.val( i );
            
            if (i > 100)
                $this.css('background', '#BBFFBB');
            else
                $this.css('background', '#FFBBBB');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/1xt8L7co/59/

Comment: Call them directly. Don't use async.

Comment: JS is a single threaded language, I don't think you can run things in parallel here.

Comment: You can use an asynchronous method like setTimeout() for your timers rather than blocking 
while-loops

Comment: `setTimeout` does not introduce parallelism. It simply causes `runAsync` to complete (twice) before A, and then B, actually run (and A and B still run in series).

Comment: Andrew, right, I checked, setTimeout does not introduce parallelism:  https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/n2huzfxj/38/  A and B are running one after another.

Comment: Andrew, I found: "Since web workers are in external files, they do not have access to the following JavaScript objects: The window object, The document object, The parent object" Is this a way to update DOM objects by WebWorkers  ?

Comment: @MykolaUspalenko - No, not directly, but depending on your real requirements and what processing you are actually doing, you could research use of WebWorkers and how to interact between them and the UI/DOM (and then perhaps open another question with those specifics). :)

Comment: @Andrew, please review my new Plugin at https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/1xt8L7co/59/  to simulate parallel execution.

Comment: @MykolaUspalenko - it still doesn't do anything in parallel - it simply interleaves the processing of A and B. However, if your aim was for the UI to remain responsive, then yes this will probably achieve that. In IE11 it will use setTimeout, not requestIdleCallback, which may make the UI sluggish depending on the processing and the timeout used. requestIdleCallback will avoid running while the UI event loop is not empty (up until the timeout) but setTimeout will queue the function call as soon as the timeout has expired (and you have it set at 10ms so that will be often). Just experiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two example functions simply execute synchronously one after the other on the same "thread" (JS effectively has only one thread available to such scripts).

The use of `async` is irrelevant here because no truly asynchronous operation is occurring in function A - it is simply a busy while loop - so it completes in full before execution can move to anything else.

If function A had called an actual asynchronous operation (such as a HTTP request - not simply a synchronous operation wrapped in an `async` function), then function B may have a chance to start up (in which case B would complete entirely before the execution returned to A, because B is also only contains a synchronous, busy while loop).

Parallel processing can be achieved with WebWorkers which allowing running on background threads (actual separate threads).